# Passing Array of strings to PowerShell function

Tags: powershell

I have a function called BuildQuery that takes a Array of values as Parameters.

```
Function BuildQuery {
Param($start, [String[]] $KeyFields, [String] $Sch, [String] $TableName)
$Query = "select $KeyFields from '$Sch'.'$TableName'"
}
```

I want to call the function as :

```
BuildQuery -start start -KeyFields name, id, age, salary -Sch dbo -TableName Employee
```

E.g. : I want to build a query `"select  name, id, age, salary  from dbo.Employee "`
using the PowerShell function. The only reason I am using function is I want to see it again and again to build queries like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [the `-join` operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847757.aspx) to expand the array as a comma-separated list:

```
Function BuildQuery {
    Param($start, [String[]] $KeyFields, [String] $Sch, [String] $TableName)
    $Query = "select $($KeyFields -join ',') from '$Sch'.'$TableName'"
}
```

Comment: ah, you were just a tick faster :-)

Comment: @MartinBrandl you've outranked me for almost 2 weeks, great to be back at full speed :-D

Comment: Awesome! Thats exactly what I wanted! . Can't accept the Answer yet because of some time restriction.. So waiting for it to finish   :)